# Exclude code-golf and code-challenge from "Frequented Tags"

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

Recently, I started seeing over half of the questions on the site highlighted in blue.  Later, I noticed that [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) appeared under my "Frequented Tags".  [Frequented Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72587/why-is-stack-overflow-suddenly-orange) is a feature of the site where it decides what questions are interesting to you based on your viewing habits.  Apparently, I'm interested in code golf!

As a workaround, I added [dummy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dummy) to my favorite tags.

My feature request is for an exception to be made for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) and maybe [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).  In general, tags that apply to over (perhaps) 1/3 of all questions on the site should be excluded from "Frequented Tags".  Otherwise, the highlighting becomes nothing but noise.

Comment: I'm considering migrating this to the mother meta, as I don't think any such feature exists yet. Or we could give it a while here; several of the team do seem to visit. Do you have a preference in the matter?

Answer (score 2):

This logic simply looks at the tags you frequent.  You're asking for a tag to exist, but not exist.  The tag is either on the site, or it gets removed/blocked.  Can't have it both ways.  If the tag is valid on questions, it should be valid as a favorite tag.  Additionally, there are people that follow this tag voluntarily, so we can't just say "[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is not allowed to be a favorite tag".

Comment: I'm not saying [tag:code-golf] should not be allowed to be a favorite tag.  I'm saying it should not *automatically* become a "Frequented Tag".

Comment: @JoeyAdams, still seems like an arbitrary rule "sometimes tags are really tags, but sometimes we should ignore tags".

Comment: Sometimes, arbitrary rules are needed to deal with problems that occur in practice.  To quote scripture: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/rate-limiting-and-velocity-checking.html